# XAML/XML dream formatting

Tags: xml, xaml, code-formatting

How can I format XML/XAML in a specific way: e.g.

```
<Configuration><Houses><add Name="Default" Environment="General"                EnvironmentLockout ="true" LogMinimumLevel="1" AllowLocalPrinters="false"  DocumentExportPath ="Q:\" /></Houses></Configuration>
```

As I have very bad eye sight i would dream of automatically converting this to:

```
<Configuration>
   <Houses>
      <add 
        Name                ="Default" 
        Environment         ="General"              
        EnvironmentLockout  ="true" 
        LogMinimumLevel     ="1" 
        AllowLocalPrinters  ="false"  
        DocumentExportPath  ="Q:\" />
   </Houses>
</Configuration>
```

Now I know there is an option in VS to put every attribute on a different line (except the first one), but the problem remains that values are not properly aligned to attributes.

Any help would be very, very much appreciated! Any add-in, or cut and paste application would be okay

Thank you very much,

Kevin